# How do I change the gamerule from keep inventory to no keep inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a server and some person that was messing with it changed the gamerule to keep inventory but personally I do not like keep inventory. So, how do I change it back?

Comment: Also don't give OP to people you don't want changing things.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are OP, and run this command:

```
/gamerule keepInventory false
```